# Get the first element with specified class who is above the clicked element

Tags: jquery

So if i have the following Html structure:

```
 <div class='main'> </div>
 <div class='main'> </div>
 <div class='main'> </div> <!-- the element i want to get -->
     <div class="second"> </div>
     <div class="second"> </div> <!-- element clicked -->
     <div class="second"> </div>
<div class='main'> </div>
<div class='main'> </div>


$(document).on('click', 'second', function(){
  $(this). ?
}
```

How can i get the first element from bottom with the class `main` above the clicked div ?

All this classes have also an unique id witch i will get `('.main').attr('id')`, but i need to somehow get the first element with the class `name` that is above the cliked element.

Comment: as per your html where do you click and what will be the output ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question but, if doesn't matter what second element you want to click, and you want always to get the last main element, you can do in this way in vanilla javascript:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main-container')
const second = document.querySelector('.second-container')

second.addEventListener('click',function(){
 let last = main.lastElementChild
  console.log(last)
})
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class='main'>main 1 </div>
 <div class='main'> main 2</div>
 <div class='main'> main3</div>
</div>

 <div class="second-container">
   <div class="second"> second1</div>
     <div class="second">second2 </div> <!-- element clicked -->
     <div class="second">second 3 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $target = $($this.siblings('.main').get().reverse().find(x=>$(x).index()<index))
```

this is it.

find all the siblings with class '.main',get them reverse

and find the first one that index less than the one you clicked

```js
$(".second").on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    var index = $this.index()
    var $target = $($this.siblings('.main').get().reverse().find(x=>$(x).index()<index))
    console.log($target)
})
```

```css
div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.main{
    outline: 1px red solid;
}

.second{
    outline: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'> </div>
<div class='main'> </div>
<div class='main'> </div> <!-- the element i want to get -->
<div class="second"> </div>
<div class="second"> </div> <!-- element clicked -->
<div class='main'> </div>
<div class='main'> </div>
<div class="second"> </div>
<div class="second"> </div>
```